# Why does R not handle daylight savings consistently among years?

Tags: r, date, timezone, dst, posixct

I encountered a strange situation while converting time stamps between "America/Detroit" and "GMT". Upon closer inspection I discovered that R converted times between 1 and 2 am on the day daylight savings ends differently in 2010 and 2011. In 2010 it listed those times as being in "EDT" and in 2011 it listed those times in "EST". The result was that conversion to GMT added 4 hours in one case and 5 hours in the other. Can anyone she light on this situation and suggest a solution for correcting this inconsistency?

```
a = as.POSIXct("2010-11-07 01:58:00", tz = "America/Detroit")
#[1] "2010-11-07 01:58:00 EDT"

b = as.POSIXct("2011-11-06 01:58:00", tz = "America/Detroit")
# [1] "2011-11-06 01:58:00 EST"

format(c(a,b), tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2010-11-07 05:58:00" "2011-11-06 06:58:00"
```

Comment: Your example gives me `"2010-11-07 05:58:00" "2011-11-06 05:58:00"` on Linux with R version 3.2.2.

Comment: I tried this on a OSX version 3.2.2, Windows version 3.1.1 and 3.1.3, and Linux version 3.1.3 and got the same result every time. Is it possible the zoneinfo files are out of date?

Comment: Just noticed that on my machine, result for `b` is `"2011-11-06 01:58:00 EDT"`, not `EST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The times that you give are ambiguous.  As the clock is "fallen back" at 2, the local time 1:58 for these days occurs twice on each day, once in EDT and again in EST.

Both are correct, as you do not specify which you mean.

The OS library code for this will (probably) use an iterative algorithm, ending when the `time_t` value derived agrees with the `struct tm` value passed to `mktime`.  Because of this, the results will be essentially random.

Here's an example:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ntp/ntp-13/ntp/libntp/mktime.c

Comment: Your explanation would make more sense to me if the results were random, but these results are consistent between computers, operating system, and R versions. This suggests to me that R is using a set of rules to assign the time zone, which are not consistent between years? I just tried a bunch of different times and it seems like In 2011 it switches from EDT to EST at 2011-11-06 01:50:00 and in 2010 it changes from EDT to EST at 2010-11-07 01:58:23. Does anyone know where to look to find where these rules are defined?

Comment: @user5270480 By "essentially random" I mean that you can't depend on them.  You might get different results from different platforms, and even potentially different results on the same platform from calls made at different times.  My point in this answer is that the rules cannot be defined, because your input is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to write a work-around to solve my specific issue. Seems to me that R would be better off providing a results of NA for such ambiguities, but at least now that I know it happens, I can look for it in the future.